# How to change collation for Azure SQL Data warehouse and Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, collation, azure-synapse

Can i change sql collation for Azure SQL Data warehouse and Azure SQL Database from Latin to another collation in exiting resource?
Who can help and recommend me about my issue. please help suggestion me.

Thanks,

za_phu

Answer (score 1):

For Azure SQL Database (link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-2017)) and Azure SQL Data Warehouse, you cannot change the database collation once you create the database. You can change the collation of columns using the [COLLATE keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-2017). The doc for [COLLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation?view=sql-server-2017) incorrectly shows DW not supported but it is supported.